# RegEx match part of a string as long as the next character is not _

Tags: regex

I'm sure this is a simple regex, but I couldn't figure out the wording to get what I wanted out of a Google/SO search.

In the following string, I want to match **foo** as long as the **next character is not _** *(underscore)*

> Lorem ipsum dol**foo_**or sit amet, consectetur**foo** ut aliquip ex ea
>   commodo consequat. Duis aute ir**foo**ure dolor in reprehenderit in
>   vol**foo_**uptate velit esse cillum dolore eu  sunt in culpa qui
>   offic**foo**ia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

I should get 3 matches here all **foo** and ignore the other two **foo_** instances. I've got this so far;

```
foo[^_]
```

Which returns this;

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => foo 
        [1] => foou
        [2] => fooi
    )
```

This matches one character after foo, which is not what I want. I don't know how to *not* match the next character at the same time as saying it must not be and underscore...Please educate me!

For reference this is for matching in a text editor, so I'm slightly limited to what I can do, which is why I need to match that exact string and nothing else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
foo(?!_)
```

The above negative lookahead asserts that the match `foo` won't be followed by an underscore symbol.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bP0xU1/2)

Comment: Perfect - I wasn't aware of a negative lookahead.